# Handling post requests done via HTML form submission in React JS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a ReactJS app which needs to handle a post request from a HTML form submit action(Generated by a SSO entity) and extract the token from it.

Below is the HTML code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit Form</title>
        <meta name="referrer" content="origin"/>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/">
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="ETiHVg9Gg52Edmm2wpRr07VXsMgLnnQ"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

For an asp.net app, i am able to extract it as `string token1 = Request.Form["token"];`

How can I achieve the same in React JS.

Comment: sry didnt get u, ReactJS app doesnt handle post request from HTML forms,   usually submitting a html form action goes to backend(node, php,...) React is a client side lib. or are you referring how to send hidden form values in react js....

Answer (score 0):

In React, when working with forms or any other user input fields such as standalone text fields or buttons. From React’s documentation: “React components must represent the state of the view at any point in time and not only at initialization time.” React is all about keeping things simple by using declarative style to describe UIs. React describes the UI, its end stage, and how it should look.

In the traditional HTML form elements, the state of the elements will change with the user input. React uses a declarative approach to describe the UI. The input needs to be dynamic to reflect the state properly.